# Email Reports from Google Analytics

Tags: google-analytics

Are weekly email reports of website statistics from Google Analytics still available with since the latest updates/redesign?

*EDIT: and does anyone know of any plans to bring this back, if it has been discontinued?*

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This seems to be still working, and this is how I believe it is done:

- Sign into your Google Analytics account
- Click on `Standard Reporting`
- Click on `Email BETA`
- Enter your email address and Subject in their respective fields
- Click on the ", CSV" drop down menu to choose one report format
- Ensure Weekly is selected next to the Frequency label
- Click on your day of the week
- Type your message in the white pane
- Click on the `Send` button

[image]

Comment: I thought about your problem while reading [Automate Informative Google Analytics Reports With Custom Reporting](http://www.makeuseof.com/tag/automate-informative-google-analytics-reports-custom-reporting/).